# Option to boot into Windows missing after Boot Camp Assist

Tags: bootcamp, partition, startup, windows

I just completed installing Windows using Bootcamp Assist. I allocated 30 GB to the Windows partition. The process completed after taking a long time (> 7 hours), and a Bootcamp partition has been created.

System specs:
MacBook Pro (Retina Mid 2012) with MacOS Sierra (10.12). I downloaded Windows 10 from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

However, there is no option to boot into Windows. Even if I press Option+Shift+Commad+Period as suggested in another [post](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796#startupmanager), i dont get the option to boot into Windows.

[image]

There is no Windows start up disk

[image]

But the Bootcamp partition has been made, and it has taken 30 GB

[image]

Here are the disk details

[image]

I did a NVPRAM reset as suggested in another [post](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204063), but it didn't change anything. The external USB disk now has the following files:

[image]

Should I erase the Bootcamp partition and start over again? If so, can i use Disk Utility to erase the Bootcamp partition?